# React Typescript - variable null check ignored and sends error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Javascript newbie here^^

In my React front, I have the following chrome error message :

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'style' of null

▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.

new LiquidFillGauge

SOMEPATH/liquidFillGauge.tsx:46

  43 | var gauge = d3.select('#' + elementId);
  44 | var radius = 0, locationX = 0, locationY = 0;
  45 | if (gauge != null && gauge != undefined) {
> 46 |     radius = Math.min(parseInt(gauge.style('width')), parseInt(gauge.style('height'))) / 2;
  47 | ^   locationX = parseInt(gauge.style('width')) / 2 - radius;
  48 |     locationY = parseInt(gauge.style('height')) / 2 - radius;
  49 | }
```

gauge being exceedingly checked in line 45, it still appears null in line 46.

Why is that happening ? How could I avoid the error ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
if(gauge){
   radius = Math.min(parseInt(gauge.style('width')), parseInt(gauge.style('height'))) / 2; 
   locationX = parseInt(gauge.style('width')) / 2 - radius;
   locationY = parseInt(gauge.style('height')) / 2 - radius;
}
```

In javascript or typescript a null or undefined returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Because `==` stands just for equal type. You ought to use `===` which stands for **equal type** and **equal value**.

See this example:

```
let a = null;
let isNull = a != null;
```

> isNull = false

To check `null`, `undefined`, `false`, you could do:

```
isEmpty = !gauge;
```